# Set tag value on select2

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have select field on my page:

```
<label>
    <span>Select name</span>
    <select name="name">
        <option value="Option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="Option2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

And I have initialized select2 lib for this field:

```
$("[name='name']").select2({
    allowClear: true,
    tags: true
});
```

As you can see I need to use tags because user can write an option, not included in the proposed.

And it works.

When I want to set the default user value I use this command:

```
$("[name='name']").val(Option1).trigger("change");
```

And it works if the value is one of the select options values. But if I want set other value, the tag doesn't set.

```
$("[name='name']").val(Option3).trigger("change");
```

What can I do to set tag value?

Comment: please create a fiddle or any demo for this

Answer (score 4):

ok, I found the answer!
If we don't have an option with tag value, we just do something like this:

```
var tagValue = [{id: Option3, text: Option3}];

$("[name='name']").select2({
    allowClear: true,
    tags: true,
    data: tagValue
});

$("[name='name']").val(tagValue).trigger('change');
```

So, the first part of this code makes an additional option in our select and after that we can use it as value to set it.

Comment: Were you able to use this to set multiple tags as well? If so, could you please provide an example? Also, you can accept your own answer