# set values to select2 multiple with angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-select2

I want to set my multi select2 pragmatically with default data that is array of integers.

```
<select class="form-control select2_multiple" ng-selected="name.FeatureArray"  multiple="multiple" ng-model="name.FeatureArray" ng-options="Record.Id as Record.Text for Record in FeatureList"></select>
```

select element in html generates options dynamically by using ng-repeat and the list of FeatureList is

```
$scope.FeatureList = [{id:1, text:'AK120'},
{id:2, text:'AK120'},
{id:3, text:'AP170'},
{id:4, text:'AS130'},
{id:5, text:'AK160'},
{id:6, text:'AW110'},
{id:7, text:'AV190'},
{id:8, text:'AN120'},
{id:9, text:'AR130'}]
```

let say function foo is called to set ng-model `$scope.name.FeatureArray = [1,2,6,7];` to multi select2. when I open up the drop down i can see the values highlighted but I can not see tags on the element

I tried this which was posted here [at Anastasiia answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767515/set-tag-value-on-select2#comment64906488_38767515)

```
var tagValue = [{id: Option3, text: Option3}];
$("[name='name']").select2({
    allowClear: true,
    tags: true,
    data: tagValue
});
$("[name='name']").val(tagValue).trigger('change');
```

but neither this worked

Should I provide more info?

Comment: Hey, this is not exactly an answer, so here it is in a comment: 

There's this nifty tool that does what select2 does the angular way, you can find it here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

Comment: Hi groooves! thanks for suggestion I already tried ui-select but its not working for me neither it is working on their plunker here : [plunker link](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/demo-multiple-selection.html)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/maku/TXPJZ/ suggesting you this link

Comment: Thanks Aravind it seems like like working let me mold it to my scenario

Comment: Hi Aravind I tried to fix the external links but i was unable to fix them can you please update the jsfiddle